# Installing python mysql client on mac os fails

Tags: mysql, python-requests

I'm trying to install the requirements locally on mac os 11.4
but I get the following exception:

```
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/zl/gn1br8zd3cs265m_663x8rn00000gn/T/pip-install-k968bfcz/mysqlclient_0c41bc6e82d443fd971be8071ae4b971/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/zl/gn1br8zd3cs265m_663x8rn00000gn/T/pip-install-k968bfcz/mysqlclient_0c41bc6e82d443fd971be8071ae4b971/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/zl/gn1br8zd3cs265m_663x8rn00000gn/T/pip-record-n29c9tcu/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/mac/Library/Python/3.8/include/python3.8/mysqlclient
         cwd: /private/var/folders/zl/gn1br8zd3cs265m_663x8rn00000gn/T/pip-install-k968bfcz/mysqlclient_0c41bc6e82d443fd971be8071ae4b971/
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.26/include/mysql -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Wl,-headerpad,0x1000 build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.26/lib -lmysqlclient -lz -lzstd -lssl -lcrypto -lresolv -o build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/zl/gn1br8zd3cs265m_663x8rn00000gn/T/pip-install-k968bfcz/mysqlclient_0c41bc6e82d443fd971be8071ae4b971/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/zl/gn1br8zd3cs265m_663x8rn00000gn/T/pip-install-k968bfcz/mysqlclient_0c41bc6e82d443fd971be8071ae4b971/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/zl/gn1br8zd3cs265m_663x8rn00000gn/T/pip-record-n29c9tcu/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/mac/Library/Python/3.8/include/python3.8/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

The last line suggests to check the log, but where is the log?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/169):

what you need to do is call

```
brew info openssl
```

and than follow the steps which are presented by the command